# If I Fork a process in ruby, do I need to reconnect to Mysql DB?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, fork

I'm using the following environment.

- Rails 3.1
- Unicorn
- Mysql

I have to fork a process wich generate invoces. People told me to use

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!
```

Because with some drivers could lost the connection with fork...
I looked for some information about that but I'm more confused than before... here comes my doubts:

**1 What's the difference between using**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!
```

and

```
::ActiveRecord::Base.clear_all_connections!
```

before forking and

```
::ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
```

as shown here? [Mysql, using fork in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913476/using-fork-in-ruby-on-rails-for-creating-parallel-process)

**2 Should I do it always?**

If the answer is `YES`there is some place to put it as "fork configuration"?

**3 what's happen with the connection when the forked process ends?**
should I close it? or does it close automatically? and what's append to the father's process connection?

**4 Is it needed for all database connections?**

I have read somewhere that is only for Postgres DB...

Thank you

Comment: of course you have to. do you think they ahare variables

Answer (score 0):

No, from my point of view you dont have to reconnect.. You only have to connect if you want to access a different database, as far as i know rails handles the reconnect by its own for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish a new connection in your fork even it has no database access.

Because when then forked process exit, it will close the connection it copied, which is the same connection its parent process is using, this may interrupt the parent process. Vise versa.